# List = csv.collect(), then df.column.isin(List)) not working?

Tags: pyspark

After looking at the documentation and looking at some stackoverflow posts, I tried two different methods, but I feel I might be doing something wrong before that.

To start off, this is what `some_list_without_header.csv` looks like:

```
12345
23456
34567
```

```
schema_for_list = StructType([StructField('_c0', StringType())])

some_list = spark.read.csv("some_list_without_header.csv", header=False, schema = schema_for_list).collect()

###

schema_for_data = StructType([
  StructField('COLUMN_TO_CHECK', StringType()),
  StructField('COLUMN2', StringType())
])

data = spark.read.csv("data.csv", header = True, schema = schema_for_data)

### Tried few ways, here are couple examples, neither working

data.filter(data.COLUMN_TO_CHECK.isin(some_list))

data.where(F.col('COLUMN_TO_CHECK').isin(some_list))
```

Here is the error message

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit.
: org.apache.spark.SparkRuntimeException: The feature is not supported: literal for '[EXAMPLE_NUMBER_STRING]' of class java.util.ArrayList.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.literalTypeUnsupportedError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:296)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.apply(literals.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.lit(functions.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit(functions.scala)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: You probably don't get what you expect when you print out `some_list`

Comment: @ScootCork This is indeed true! I assumed it would be a list. After searching online, I wasn't able to turn it into a list. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: You can try `some_list = [row[0] for row in some_list]` to get a list of the first elements of each row.